# Stateful forwarding rule in iptables

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

I have created this bridge device

```
ip link add dev br0 type bridge
ip addr add 172.16.0.254/16 broadcast 172.16.255.255 dev br0
ip link set br0 up
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.br0.forwarding=1
```

This device is used by a virtual machine, but I can't seam to get it working the way I would like. I tried using the following iptables rules.

```
iptables -A FORWARD -o br0 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i br0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -s 172.16.0.0/16 -j MASQUERADE
```

With these rules the virtual machines cannot access the internet. If I instead just allow everything, it works fine.

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i br0 -j ACCEPT
```

The `conntrack` module is loaded. I am simply testing setting up rules that will allow forwarding any trafic initiated by the virtual machine, but reject all other incoming trafic.

Comment: Your rules are unusual. One filters traffic _from_ your VMs, the other filters traffic _to_ your VMs. Do you really need both?

Comment: Proplably not. I am trying to get more familiar with iptables besides the normal firewall things like opening a port and such.

Comment: If I only use conntrack on output and accept all on input it works, but not the other way around. Maybe I am misunderstanding what input and output is on iptables? Would input not be whatever is passed from host to the bridge as incoming/response? And output would be whatever the virtual machine initiates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably because you have `-i` and `-o` backwards, so your rules only allow 'NEW' packets *to* VMs but not *from* them.

> Maybe I am misunderstanding what input and output is on iptables? Would input not be whatever is passed from host to the bridge as incoming/response?

No. If you're talking about the -i/-o options, then they aren't "input/output" in general – they mean "input/output *interface* for this packet". A forwarded packet has *both* 'in' and 'out' fields filled in, and the actual interface that you specify together with those options is what ultimately makes the rule "output to VM" versus "output to Internet", or "input from VM" &c.

- For example, if your VM wants to initiate a connection to e.g. Google, it will first send a SYN packet that the host receives through (-i) br0 and is about to forward through (-o) wlan0. So the rule that permits "NEW from the VM" should be `-i br0`.
- The reply packet from Google will subsequently be received through (-i) wlan0, un-NAT'd, and forwarded to the VM via (-o) br0.

  But the third packet will again be from (-i) br0, etc. So the 'ESTABLISHED' packets need to be allowed in both directions, and you could just have a rule that does so without any interface check at all.

---

(And if you're talking about iptables chains, then 'INPUT' is packets that are destined for the host's own IP address, i.e. the ones that are *not* forwarded anywhere further. (This check is done during routing, so it happens after conntrack has already done its un-NAT.) Similarly, 'OUTPUT' is used for packets that the host itself has generated.)

Comment: So that would mean that `-i` is comming from the VM and `-o` is going to the VM?

Comment: No, it means that `-i br0` *specifically* is coming from the VM (because the host just received that packet via br0) and `-o br0` is going to the VM (because the host is about to send that packet via br0). These options ask iptables to check the in/out interfaces that the packet travels through.

Comment: I get it. I am looking at this from the perspective of the VM and not the Host/Bridge. So output from the bridge to the VM and input from the VM to the bridge.